# Select Html with php & mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I've this problem:

```
<select name="plag" id="plag">

        <?php

        while ($res = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        echo "<option value=\"".$res['idPlage']."\">".$res['ComunName']."</option>";
        }

        ?>
    </select>
```

I need to get an ID from select but i also want to show a name from id. is it possible to get a option values with php?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is Hmlt?

Comment: Can we see the query?

Comment: *great* comment dylan! :(

Comment: Public service announcement: [the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php), and [you should use a PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for your MySQL connections instead.

Comment: you don't send the $query to mysql_fetch_array, you send the $result of the query, such as: $result = mysql_query($query); while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) )...

Comment: @shad0w, show us the value of $query

Answer (score 0):

You have the value you need in the database already. Just go and get it the value you are looking for using the ID submitted with the form.

A hackish alternative is to append the value to the ID and place that as the vaue in your drop down. You can then use `substr()` or `explode()` to get it when the form is submitted.

Comment: include("conn.php"); 

$query = mysql_query("SELECT idPlage,ComunName FROM Plage");

Comment: John Conde...Could u do an example, please?

Answer (score 0):

Simply select the two columns from the database like so, then cycle through them using `mysql_fetch_array`. You must specify the column names in the `$res['']` exactly as they appear in the table.

```
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT idPlage,ComunName FROM Plage");
    while ($res = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_result($query))){
       echo "<option value=\"".$res['idPlage']."\">".$res['ComunName']."</option>";
    }
```

Alternative way of doing it:

```
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT idPlage,ComunName FROM Plage");
    $num_rows=mysql_num_rows($result);

    while ($i<$num_rows){
       echo "<option value=\"".mysql_result($query,$i,'idPlage')."\">".mysql_result($query,$i,'ComunName')."</option>";
    }
```

Comment: the columns should be selected from a table

Comment: well you know, usually we call the query string $query, and save it in $result, and then we get the $row in the while-loop

Comment: I do know that yes, but he has pretty much got all the code for the alternative to doing it the traditional way ;)

Comment: I shall add in the alternative solution then ;) thanks for the heads up